How can I replace the gradle repositories in flutter plugins?
My flutter module project used some third flutter plugin which used higher version gradle, and I cannot download it. So flutter build aar always failed. I have to set repository mirror to download it.
When using flutter v3.3.4, I can change the flutter.gradle file in SDK, add repository to solve this problem. But in flutter 3.22.2, there is no such file.
Have tried to add repository to files like resolve_dependencies.gradle, build.gradle.kts in flutter 3.22.3, none of it works.
